# Maximum array size in objective C on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, arrays, size, max

I have a VERY large array (96,000 elements of type GLfloat). It was previously 24,000 elements, until I made a couple of changes. Now I'm getting a crash. I haven't done much to debug it yet, but when I noticed how ridiculously large one of my arrays was getting I thought it might be worth looking into. So, my only question is whether 96,000 elements (or 384,000 bytes) is too much for a single array?

Comment: Any code? What did the crash say? (EXC_BAD_ACCESS?)

Comment: Where/how is the array allocated? (e.g. is it an issue of stack vs. heap allocation?) Also, you'll need to ensure 32-bit variables to represent the indexes (perhaps a subtle change from the ~24k).

Comment: The first time it crashed I got "Received memory warning. Level = 1." followed by EXC_BAD_ACCESS. The second time I only got the memory warning, no bad access, but it still crashed the same way. The array is allocated globally and non-dynamically. The crash doesn't occur when it's allocated, it occurs later when I'm using most of its elements (I use 32-bit integers to access the indices so that shouldn't be the problem).

Comment: I should mention that I'm passing this as a color array to glColorPointer. Could there be a limit on batch rendering in OpenGL? In this case I'm rendering up to 8000 triangles at once.

Comment: Show code and a crash log. Otherwise this only results in guesswork.

Answer (score 2):

That should be fine on the heap, but you should avoid allocations of that size on the stack. So `malloc/free` or `new[]/delete[]` is what you should use to create and destroy an array of that size.

If the device has low memory, you can expect requests for large amounts of memory to occasionally return `NULL`. There are applications (such as photo/image processing) which request allocations at tens of megabytes -- many times greater than your 384 KiB allocation.

Comment: For those of you who are as unfamiliar with objc/c++/c as me: replace `double data[count];` with `double* data = new double[count];`

Answer (score 1):

There is no upper bound on the size of an array, save the amount of available RAM on the device.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's too big. Some image resources would take up that much or more contiguous space without problem. For example, a 400x400px image would take about 160,000*4 = 640,000 bytes of memory. I think the problem is somewhere else.